# Check for a specific datatype in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to check if a datagridview cell contains a specific datatype. I Can’t find the right syntax for this. This is what I want.

```
If DataGridView1.Columns("Name").ValueType = String Then

End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you loop through all the rows in your datagridview, then you loop through all the cells in that row.  When looping through the cells, you check if the `Cell.Value` is a String, Integer, Decimal and so on.

Here is how:

```
    For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each Cell As DataGridViewCell In Row.Cells
            If TypeOf (Cell.Value) Is String Then
                MsgBox("This cell is a string!")
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Alternatively you can loop through the rows and immediatly check the cells by setting an index... So `Row.Cells(0).Value` will take the first cell's value:

```
    For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If TypeOf (Row.Cells(0).Value) Is String Then
            MsgBox("String again!")
        End If
    Next
```